# How way around it, my behavior OnContentRead executed when uploading files? I don't need it

Tags: java, alfresco, development-environment, behavior

I configured behavior "onContentRead", and I wanna that is executed only when I read files.

And now it also has been executing this behavior when I upload files:(

Anyone could help me? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Java Developer a.sokolov.

Comment: What action are you using the upload the file? Are you doing it programatically?

Comment: @Lista Just used drag&drop from my computer to alfresco